# Sum cell reference across all sheets to the left

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet with sheets from December 2014 to current. I need a formula  (or macro) that will sum cell H2 across all sheets to the left of the current sheet (including current sheet) to give a running total. So the sheet for February 2015 would sum December 2014, January 2015, and February 2015. Preferably a formula that can be copied and pasted into the next month without editing, as I won't be maintaining this workbook.

Comment: `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!H2)` works and your sheets probably still have those codenames

Comment: @Raystafarian That is really weird... Excel actually tracks the order of the sheets and picks up whatever is between the first sheet in the formula and the second sheet... I never knew it could do that.